# Encryption problem?

Tags: encryption, hash

what type of encryption is this?

qQzsfohbirnu5VGUG8gN92iWYRzIAIgUcZfGHyqDqy1HQKGoc1i0CsLkRci71awepmZLTbkBFo30hrMeAWjWUer7lZ3Yv8L6vsuH/sLtaN68zPWIl/7i6y28M+uIhoVOLTqTi3/ldP1Z2AJ7VlJuV22NoR3MIPEaIqaWdvkmk6aOAivbiS4DRH/z8hx7pHs6d5vtRKWehNdn9aGTtH6R+pu9v0W/Bp0JuA+VIRSIzUhlUAuCbKjwUxEMzAqSXz0SKTNkEgz4IWXrpaVwilixoWn6Vk58aT8kTAQNAXZ3Dv2tSQ/vASgQv+9iqCNp+HptEy0FLSVRRcPrSdvAhV+WKYsqXSYfegh4SiuiJgsl6zTV5TNYOUFYsoUSAdKZzquMc36wGX7L4cfY14XAspfyog==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s not encryption at all, it looks to me like an ssh public key in OpenSSH format. The `==` at the end is what gives it away, it’s Base64 padding.

Comment: So what to do with it ?

Comment: @Hordat As it seems to be an SSH public key, and you need to ask what to do, the answer is "nothing". Regarding base64, it's easy to decode it with one of thousands programs or onlien tools available, but it won't get you anything useful.

Comment: @Hordat You can use it to allow ssh access to anyone who has the matching private key. Nothing else.